# Get location and size of a winform on windows desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, location, height, width

I want to get location, height and width of a winform on Windows desktop after resize event fire. I try the code below:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Winform :" + Form1.Instance.DesktopBounds);
        }
    }
```

Although I resize the winform many times, the value of Form1.Instance.DesktopBounds is not change.
[image]

I just wanto to get location, height and width of the winform when I resize it.
Could you give me some advice? And where am I wrong with the code above?

Comment: I want to know the size and location of it before it is minimized to taskbar. Form1.Instance to get my instance. I use Singleton pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RestoreBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.restorebounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

> Gets the location of the form in its normal window state.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Winform :" + Form1.Instance.RestoreBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grant, RestoreBounds attribute solved my problem.